# TumblingEventTimeWindow not producing any output

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been trying to create a dedupe processor on TumblingEventTimeWindow but it seems like the window is never closed and so process function is not called hence no events are fired.

I have defined the flinkSource as

```
private DataStream<String> flinkStreamFromConfig(SourceTopic sourceTopic, StreamExecutionEnvironment flinkEnv){
        KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource.<String>builder()
                .setBootstrapServers(sourceTopic.getServers())
                .setTopics(sourceTopic.getTopicName())
                .setGroupId(sourceTopic.getGroupId())
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new SimpleStringSchema())
                .build();
        return flinkEnv.fromSource(source, WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(10)), sourceTopic.getTopicName());
}
```

This kafka source stream is getting created properly but when Tumbling Event Time window is applied, it never outputs any result

DataStream dedupeStream = flinkStream.windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(25))).process(new DedupeProcessor());

This is the process function which is never executed

```
public class DedupeProcessor extends ProcessAllWindowFunction<String, String, TimeWindow> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DelayedWatermarkStrategy.class);
    @Override
    public void process(ProcessAllWindowFunction<String, String, TimeWindow>.Context context, Iterable<String> elements, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        HashSet<String> seenKeys = new HashSet<>();
        StreamSupport.stream(elements.spliterator(), false).forEach(seenKeys::add);
        logger.info("emitting event {} at {}", System.currentTimeMillis(), seenKeys);
        seenKeys.forEach(out::collect);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?
I tried to debug what might be the cause in which I saw that internalTimerService.currentWatermark() is set to Long.Min and is not changing.

I tried changing event time window to processing time window and it worked with that but not working with this.

Also in debugger I could see that window was changing to new window as new events were ingested but  this if block in official code of flink window operator was never hitting, the trigger result was always continue and never fire.

```
                if (triggerResult.isFire()) {
                    ACC contents = windowState.get();
                    if (contents == null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    emitWindowContents(window, contents);
                }
```

Also input topic is a single partition.

Comment: Are you sure that you're sending in records that allow the watermark to be progressed? If you only emit records that are in your window, then Flink doesn't get an indication that time has passed and the window should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your watermark strategy doesn't declare how timestamps are extracted from the incoming String values, so unless you've got records being pushed into Kafka with metadata (for the write time), no watermarks will be assigned. That in turn will mean no event time windows will fire, and thus your process function won't get called.

If you know that your Kafka topic has metadata with timestamps, then the issue could be that your source parallelism is > 1. Since you only have one partition, and a `.windowAll()` runs with an implicit parallelism of 1, this means that you'll have <source parallelism - 1> incoming channels to the window/process that aren't generating any data (idle), and thus not advancing the watermarks.

If that's the case, either set your source parallelism to 1 (what I would do), or set up your watermark strategy to use `.withIdleness(duration)`.

Comment: Aren't timestamp by default taken as producer timestamp? Does flink not automatically extract timestamp - message.timestamp.type which is set to CreateTime in my case?

Comment: Yes, assuming your Kafka topic has timestamps assigned to records. If that's the case, I've edited my answer to provide another explanation.